# Laravel 5.7 : Supervisorctl does not auto-restart queue worker with

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue, daemon, supervisord

I have supervisor for managing queue notifications as suggested in the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#supervisor-configuration) . I have configured the supervisor as per the documentation and here is my configuration file.

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/application/artisan queue:work --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/application/storage/logs/worker/worker.log
```

This works fine but the problem is after sometime all the workers stops and doesn't restart even though there is pending jobs to be completed.

I need to manually restart the supervisor using `sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*`.

How can this be resolved ?

[Supervisorctl does not auto-restart daemon queue worker when hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759609/supervisorctl-does-not-auto-restart-daemon-queue-worker-when-hanging) This is similar problem but the solution given there is the same thing i am using here.

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Have you checked any logs on your server, if so are there any errors in there?

Answer (score 1):

You could use horizon. horizon handles all this for you.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/horizon

Example supervisor script for horizon:

```
[program:horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=php /var/www/application/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/application/storage/logs/horizon.log
```

Also add this command to your deploy-process:

```
php artisan horizon:terminate
```

No need to restart it, supervisor does that for you.

Comment: Okay seems interesting, let me try with this :)