# How to send Bulk email in laravel using SMTP Driver without creating multiple smtp client/session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, smtp, exchange-server

How can I send bulk email lets say about 1000 to 2000 emails without using queue?

I am using own Exchange server, that's why i don't want to use mailgun, maildrill,mailchimp etc., I want to stick to laravel default "STMP" driver.

Currently, the problem I am facing is that when I try to send email in bulk the application tries to create multiple session/client each for one email. But the Exchange server has a restriction of 15 clients but each client can send any number of emails.

How can I force the SMTP to send emails only though one client, rather than opening new client/session for each email?

Comment: why don't you want to use a queue, that is madness? If you want to send that amount of emails your application will timeout.

Comment: queue has one problem is that i need to run `supervisor` to run the queue process continuously. But problem with that is its getting stopped and there is no way of knowing when the process has been stopped. I tried to look for solutions even posted on SO but no optimal solution so far 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260243/laravel-5-7-supervisorctl-does-not-auto-restart-queue-worker-with?noredirect=1#comment99137265_56260243

Comment: Different service providers like octane, sendgrid, sendinblue provides api for bulk submission. You can awail their service to send bulk sms, email etc. You have to first prepare a packet of subscribers and send to them all at once.

Comment: @AnkitVishwakarma, This server has its own mail Exchange server but with a limit on how many clients/sessions can be created. But each client can send unlimited number of emails.